# How do I interact with a dynamic id through python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to click on an icon in a web page. This is the element I am attempting to click:

```
<a class="Button ButtonIcon IconOnly DataSelector NormalState" 
id="ze6402ef81ea54445aec5dab8790c781f" tabindex="0"><span class="Icon"></span>
<span class="Text"></span></a>
```

I have no problem interacting with the code below:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('ze6402ef81ea54445aec5dab8790c781f').click()
```

The problem is that the id is dynamic with each session. I have attempted a workaround with the following code with no success:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[span/@class='Text']").click()
```

and

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[span/@class='Icon']").click()
```

Afterwards, I noticed that the element needs to be in a hover state in order to be clicked. So next, I used ActionChains to try to simulate a hover state -- again, with no success:

```
actions=ActionChains(browser)
element=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("//a[span/@class='Icon']")
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Then, I tried to TAB to the element via send_keys and ActionChains -- but it ended up cycling rapidly through page, instead of one element at a time:

```
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

I wanted to put in my due diligence before posting my issue. Any assistance is appreciated - Thank you.

Comment: Can you update the question with a couple of example values of the ids (e.g. `ze6402ef81ea54445aec5dab8790c781f`) which gets generated?

Comment: #zfaf974d8e18d44cc9bfdd942643b200d, #z134860f30a964156aea8d63f98a10cee, #z978fad99632e4f44a54e67a3cae4c935

Comment: Please post a link to the page. We need more of the surrounding HTML to give an answer.

Comment: I can't do that. It requires a login to access it.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you don't have a problem with the following line of code:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('ze6402ef81ea54445aec5dab8790c781f').click()
```

But the only issue here is that the `id` is dynamic, so we can use the `class` attribute to construct an unique `cssSelector` or an unique `xpath` as follows:

- **`cssSelector`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Button.ButtonIcon.IconOnly.DataSelector.NormalState"));
  ```
- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Button ButtonIcon IconOnly DataSelector NormalState']"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use these XPaths:

```
//span[@class='Text']
//span[@class='Icon']
```

Yours were formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Here is the code I just entered -- with no change in results: 'browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='Text'].click()'. When I use 'Icon' instead of 'Text', it clicked a different element on the page.

Comment: That means that you have multiple span elements with the class name of Icon. I wonder if it is the same with Text. Try using the following format to select the second span with the class values: "(//span[@class='Text])[2]"

Comment: I entered the following: browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='Text])[2]"). I received this error:SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Put the quote in the parantheses: browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//span[@class='Text'])[2]") and put an ending single quote on Text.

Comment: This maybe? I'm sorry. Just keep moving the parentheses around. It works on my machine in a different case. I use C#. browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//span[@class='Text']")[2])